# IIS 7.0 URL REWRITE

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am setting up a redirect to WWW for one of our sites in the web.config and ran into a small issue.  The code I have in the web.config for the rewrite is as follows :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

I'm finding that it's actually working a little too well.  Because of the pattern "example.com", I'm seeing that it's now redirecting to our live site on dev and staging because our URLS are laid out like so : dev.example.com & staging.example.com.  For the time being, I have just commented out the rewrite on these other web.configs but I'm wondering if there's a better pattern or option to get around this issue.

Comment: So you want that only `example.com` gets redirected to `www.example.com` without subdomains?

Comment: @Mivaweb Yes,  `example.com` redirects to `www.example.com` but `dev.example.com` & `staging.example.com` are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the root domain without subdomains then you should edit your pattern in the `HTTP_POST` section.

Place a `^` in front of the pattern which means start with. So If the url starts with `example.com` then it gets redirected to `www.example.com`.

If its `dev.example.com`, this rule will be ignored.

**Edit your example:**

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com" />
```